# PDO connect does not work

Tags: php, pdo

I try connect to mysql DB with PDO, but does not work.
i write:

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','user','pass');
```

returns error:

```
 Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No connection could be made because
 the target machine actively refused it.
```

please tell me , wath the PDO wants to?

phpversion: 5.3.9

host: local computer, (server - "usbwebserver")

Comment: password, user and etc is true, because if I try connect DB with mysqli and use this data, its works good. not works only PDO connect.

Comment: if you're working on your pc, using localhost, usually the username is root, and the password is the one you've setted when you did the install of mysql, or, put nothing if you didn't set any. So try this instead `$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','');`

Comment: @João Dias
No, I created the new user, his name is "user" and password is "pass", this data is true

Answer (score 4):

It's a port problem. `USBwebsever` uses mysql port **3307** instead of **3306**, so use `$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost:3307','user','pass');`

Comment: Two upvotes - but we can't know if one was from the OP - @ოთოშავაძე please accept an answer or tell us how you go it to work. That will help others who have the same problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

If no connection currently exists and mysql_query is run without specifying connection info, mysql_error returns:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

This is not true.

This is heinously deceptive:
• "target machine" indicates a database server.
• "actively refused" means a server RECEIVED the request AND DENIED it.

This leads one to believe invalid credentials have been supplied or that the specified account is not configured (Host=) as expected.

The error message should be changed to reflect the fact that no database connection (or connection information) exists.

(this is especially troublesome when working with PDO coupled with a function since functions are only aware of the variables that are passed to them)

Data source:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60315

Website and database are local, both?

Comment: << Website and database are local, both?



    Yes, both local, local server is "usbwebserver"